# How to align a fragment at the bottom of relative layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I am trying to to add fragment on a relative layout in such a way that the fragment should come at the bottom of relative layout.

How can I do this ?

Please help..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` attribute to your fragment layout in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` attribute to align any view to the bottom of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it not working, actually I have a relative layout and I am adding fragment in this relative layout. I want to align my fragment in the bottom of relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

May be your problem is like mine, 
my solution is adding a blank view before another and than add weight = 1 for this atribute